# Вытащить информацию из текста

Tags: c#, парсер

```
##########################################################
# Query made at 04/10/2016 20:23:19 UTC
# Time interval: from 03/07/2016 11:30  to 03/08/2016 12:30  UTC
##########################################################

##########################################################
# 29638, Novosibirsk (Ogourtsovo) (Russia)
# IACO index: ----
# Latitude 54-54N. Longitude 082-57E. Altitude 133 m.
##########################################################

##################################################
#  SYNOPS from 29638, Novosibirsk (Ogourtsovo) (Russia)
##################################################
201603081200 AAXX 08121 29638 12980 00403 11046 21196 30289 40462 57012 60002
                   333 11023=
201603080900 AAXX 08091 29638 42973 00604 11028 21181 30301 40473 57010
                   333 91110=
201603080600 AAXX 08061 29638 42970 00504 11061 21184 30311 40485 58010=
201603080300 AAXX 08031 29638 42972 00502 11132 21201 30321 40500 53001
                   333 21160=
201603080000 AAXX 08001 29638 12998 00503 11156 21215 30320 40501 57001 60002
                   333 21159 47047 55105=
201603072100 AAXX 07211 29638 42998 00402 11151 21214 30321 40501 57004=
201603071800 AAXX 07181 29638 42998 00503 11139 21210 30325 40505 57004=
201603071500 AAXX 07151 29638 42998 00403 11118 21201 30329 40507 52005=
201603071200 AAXX 07121 29638 12980 00503 11100 21198 30324 40501 52005 60002
                   333 11083=
```

http://www.ogimet.com/display_synops2.php?lang=en&lugar=29638&tipo=ALL&ord=REV&nil=SI&fmt=txt&ano=2016&mes=03&day=07&hora=12&anof=2016&mesf=03&dayf=08&horaf=12&send=send

Есть такой текстовый файл, я его спарсил в richtexbox, необходимо вытащить информацию до букв AAXX, то есть выходной массив должен быть таким:

```
201603081200
201603080900
201603080600
201603080300
201603080000
201603072100
201603071800
201603071500
201603071200
```

Подскажите как это сделать самым лаконичным способом?

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно только до букв AAXX, то можно так:

```
string.Substring(0, 12);
```

Если нужны остальные значения, то лучше разбить входную строку на массив:

```
string.Split(new Char [] {' ', '='});
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться `string.Split(' ')` или Regex с паттерном вида `^[0-9]{12}`

Для Regex есть онлайн сервисы, где можно составить и протестировать запрос. [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

А зачем в richtexbox его читать? Сразу в памяти делаете все операции!

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
   foreach (string line in lines)
     {
      if (line.IndexOf("AAXX") != -1)
        {
          listBox1.Items.Add( line.Substring(0,line.IndexOf("AAXX")));
         }
```

}